# How to show "No Result Found" if search value not matched to data. Json file in react

Tags: reactjs, search, react-component

i want to show "No Result Found" if search value not matched to data.Json file.

i am very new in react and i am learning the react and no idea about it..

anyone can help me please?

***i provide working live demo link : https://codesandbox.io/live/f3c1f67d5c2***

**Here is the SearchPage code:**

```
import data from './Data.json';


export const SearchPage = () => {

  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');
  function handleChange(event) {
    setSearchValue(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" value={searchValue} placeholder="Search something.." onChange={handleChange}/>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      <div className="dropdown">
      {  
            data.filter(val => {
              if (val.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())) {
                return val;
              } else if (val.toLowerCase()==!searchValue.toLowerCase()){
                
              }
              if (val.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())) {
                return val;
              } 
            }).map((val) =>{
              return(
                <div className={val.css} key={val.id}>
                    <button className='button_css' >{val.title}</button>
                </div>
              )
            })
          }        
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

**here is the data.json file:**

````
    {
        "title":"general",
        "css":"template"
    },
    {
        "title":"army",
        "css":"template"
    },
    {
        "title":"police",
        "css":"template"
    },
    {
        "title":"worker",
        "css":"second_step_hide"
    },
    {
        "title":"doctor",
        "css":"first_step_hide"
    },
    {
        "title":"teacher",
        "css":"first_step_hide"
    }
]```
````

Comment: Hello! Codesandbox link doesnt work for not logged users.

Comment: try this https://71jl6z.csb.app/

Answer (score 0):

I asigned data.filter to a variable and checked it's lentgh and based on that I printed 'not found'

here is what I did :

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import data from "./Data.json";

export const SearchPage = () => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  function handleChange(event) {
    setSearchValue(event.target.value);
  }

  let list = data.filter((val) => {
    if (val.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())) {
      return val;
    } else if (val.title.toLowerCase() == !searchValue.toLowerCase()) {
    }
    if (val.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())) {
      return val;
    }
  });

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search.."
          name="search"
          value={searchValue}
          placeholder="Search something.."
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      <div className="dropdown">
        {list.length > 0
          ? list.map((val) => {
              return (
                <div className={val.css} key={val.id}>
                  <button className="button_css">{val.title}</button>
                </div>
              );
            })
          : "no found"}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: @Jenil I updated your codesandbox, could you please check it if it's ok?